# Como esconder e retornar uma guia

Tags: c#

Boa Noite!
Estou desenvolvendo um sistema com cadastro de clientes e sou novo na programação e gostaria de saber como faço para assim que eu abrir o form somente a primeira guia permaneça aberta e quando o usuário inserir o código de um cliente, as outras abas para edição do mesmo cliente retornem.
Vou deixar o código que estou tentando abaixo, consigo com que as abas iniciem fechadas, mas elas não retornam caso insiro o código do cliente.
Agradeço muito se poderem me ajudar!

```
private void tabClientes_Layout(object sender, LayoutEventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtCodigoCli.Text == "")
        {
            tabClientes.TabPages.Remove(tabAgendamento);
            tabClientes.TabPages.Remove(tabInteracoes);
            tabClientes.TabPages.Remove(tabVendas);
        }
        else
        {
            tabClientes.TabPages.Add(tabAgendamento);
        }

        tabClientes.Refresh();
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, sugiro utilizar as propriedades Visible ou Enable e colocá-las como false.
Quando o código do cliente for inserido modifique a propriedade para true. Por exemplo:

```
if (txtCodigoCli.Text == "")
        {
            tabAgendamento.Visible(false);
            tabInteracoes.Visible(false);
            tabVendas.Visible(false);
        }
        else
        {
            tabAgendamento.Visible(true);
        }

        tabClientes.Refresh();       
    }
```